# Plot groups of stacked bars

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following code to draw a bar graph with groups.  But I'd also like to subdivide some of the bars, shading in at the bottom.  So for example, I'd like the leftmost bar to have up until the number 1 shaded/patterned.  Also, I'd like to include in the legend what the shading represents, as a single extra entry.  Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,fit,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=8cm, height=8cm,
    ybar,
    bar width=35pt,
    ymin=0,
    ymax = 6,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    xticklabels={{Did 1st},{Did 2nd}},
    x tick label style={text width=2cm,align=center},
    ylabel={Number of groups},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    area legend,
    legend style={draw=none,cells={anchor=west},legend pos=outer north east},
  ]
  \addplot [color=black,fill=cyan,point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates{(1,4) [67\%] (2,3) [50\%]};
  \addlegendentry{Experimental}
  \addplot [color=black,fill=red,point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates{(1,1) [17\%] (2,2) [33\%]};
  \addlegendentry{Control}  
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an automatic way (maybe it could be a feature request if not available), but your best bet might be to manually position a node and then manually add the entry.

I tried various ways, but this seems to be the only way.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10,
/pgfplots/patt/.style={
legend image code/.code={
\begin{scope}[yshift=-.1cm]
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (6mm,2mm);
\end{scope}
  }
 }
}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,fit,patterns,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=8cm, height=8cm,
        ybar,
        bar width=35pt,
        ymin=0,
        ymax = 6,
        xtick=data,
        enlarge x limits=0.5,
        xticklabels={{Did 1st},{Did 2nd}},
        x tick label style={text width=2cm,align=center},
        ylabel={Number of groups},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        area legend,
        legend style={draw=none,cells={anchor=west},legend pos=outer north east},
    ]
    \addplot [color=black,fill=cyan,point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates{(1,4) [67\%] (2,3) [50\%]};
    \addlegendentry{Experimental}

    \addplot [color=black,fill=red,point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates{(1,1) [17\%] (2,2) [33\%]};
    \addlegendentry{Control} 

    \node[draw,anchor=south east,pattern color=black, pattern=north west lines, minimum width=35pt,minimum height=30.3pt,xshift=-.8pt] at (0,0) {};
    \addlegendimage{patt}
    \addlegendentry{Pattern}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```